# Multiple DNS records with different networks

Tags: ubuntu, bind, openstack

So I have Ubuntu 14.04 VMs running in an OpenStack environmnet. The DNS machine has an external IP (10.14.6.3) and an internal IP (192.168.1.3). I have two other machines within the same project [h1] that has an external ip (10.14.6.4) and an internal IP (192.168.1.4) and [n1] that has an external ip (10.14.6.5) and internal IP (192.168.1.5).

h1 and n1 have the DNS Machine's IP set in their resolv.conf, and can resolve correctly.

I have also set my local machine (outside openstack) to use 10.14.6.3 as my DNS server.

In the DNS machines Bind db file, I have the following entries:

```
h1 IN A 192.168.1.4
h1 IN A 10.14.6.4
n1 IN A 192.168.1.5
n1 IN A 10.14.6.5
```

the pointer file has the following:

```
1 IN PTR h1.
2 IN PTR h1.
3 IN PTR n1.
4 IN PTR n1.
```

My local machine only can talk to the 10.14 subnet. 
I want h1 and n1 to resolve each other via the 192.168 subnet (not the 10.14).

Most of the time, this works fine. 
If I ping h1 from n1, it resolves as 192.168.1.4
If I ping h1 from my local machine, it resolves as 10.14.6.4

Occasionally however, if I ping from either machine, the other IP will be used. Sometimes my local machine resolves h1 to 192.168.1.4, which won't work.

My question is, is there a way to force a sequential resolution without using a local host file? I want the machines inside openstack to resolve each other via local IP 192.168.x.x And I want machines external to openstack to resolve the names via the machines external IPs 10.14.x.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what you want, but multiple entries for the same resource record in a single zone such as:

```
h1 IN A 192.168.1.4
h1 IN A 10.14.6.4
```

is called [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) and the effect is exactly as you describe, sometimes when accessing host h1 ip-address   192.168.1.4 is used, another time 10.14.6.4

> I want the machines inside openstack to resolve each other via local IP 192.168.x.x And I want machines external to openstack to resolve the names via the machines external IPs 10.14.x.x

You resolve that by either using [split-horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS), which allows the same hostname to be resolved differently depending where the DNS request originates from, or simply have a unique name for each ip-address, e.g. `h1.int.example.com.`  and `h1.ext.example.com.`.